# How to render Gridsome metadata (vue-meta) Server Side?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, metadata, gridsome

In Gridsome:
Seems like what is in `metaInfo` gets generated after mount, which results in no link preview when **scraped** by facebook.
The og:title, description and image are visible on client side.

How to get it generate on build so it would be in .html straight away?

I've been only able to add global data with `head.meta.push({})` in main.js

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: move `metaInfo` into `App.vue`.

Seems like it only renders `App.vue` when building and it will only call a `metaInfo()` in there - where you can use the metadata obj from `gridsome.server.js` method `createPage()`.